# Diffrentiability of modulus function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

$f(x) = (x-1)|(x-1)(x-2)|$. My teacher explained that since the since the effective power of $(x-1) = 2$ which is greater than $1$, it will be differentiable at $x = 1$. But since the effective power of $(x-2)$ is $1$, it wont be differentiable at $x = 2$.

$f(x) = |x-a|^n$

if $n < 0:$ discontinuous , non-differentiable
if $0<n\le 1:$ continuous, non differentiable
if $n>2:$ continuous, differentiable

Can somebody help me prove it and explain the deeper implications of this concept ?

Comment: Why not apply literally the definition of derivative computing the lateral limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may know, $$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$ so if we consider $f(x)=|x-a|^n,\;n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|a+h-a|^n-|a-a|^n}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|h|^n}{h}.$$
If $n\in(0,1]$ then $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{h^n}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}h^{n-1}>0$$ but $$\lim_{h\to 0^-}-\frac{h^n}{h}=-\lim_{h\to 0^+}h^{n-1}<0$$ so  $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{|h|^n}{h}\neq \lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{|h|^n}{h},$$ therefore, it is not differentiable.

On the other hand, if $n>1$ you don't face that problem.